# Cypher: get nodes attached to a group of nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know how to filter a group of nodes in Cypher:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name =~ '(?i).*Rebecca.*'
RETURN p;
```

And I know how to get all nodes that are attached (in any way) to an individual node specified by ID:

```
START a=node(4721)
MATCH (a)-->(d) 
RETURN distinct d
```

But how do I get all nodes that are attached to the filtered group, rather than an individual node?

And then, how do I filter those nodes for a particular name, in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But how do I get all nodes that are attached to the filtered group, rather than an individual node?

Labels are used for filtering groups so the query would look something like this

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:SOME_REL]->(n:Neighbours)
WITH n where n.name =~ '(?i).*Rebecca.*'
Return n
```

so now we are returning only neighbours of persons that have name Rebecca
You could also do this in one step.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:SOME_REL]->(n:Neighbours) where n.name =~ '(?i).*Rebecca.*'
Return n
```

Comment: Thanks! But it looks like the first query as written just returns all the people called Rebecca, not their neighbours?

Comment: it returns neighbours with name Rebecca not Person named Rebecca... We assign p variable for Persons and n variable for Neighbours and can return as we like or filter with WHERE clause

Comment: I see. So I want to find all the people with Rebecca somewhere in their name, then find all those people's neighbours. But when I amend the query to `MATCH (p:Person)-->(n:Neighbour) WITH p where p.name =~ '(?i).*Rebecca.*' Return p, n` I get an error message saying `n` is not defined. How can I amend this?

Comment: `MATCH (p:Person)-->(n:Neighbour) WITH p,n where p.name =~ '(?i).*Rebecca.*' Return p, n`    you must take all the variables in WITH clause that you want to use later